# Angular 17 y Bootstrap 5

Tags: nodejs, angular, bootstrap-5

ando haciendo una pagina web de practica que al final termino haciéndome usar **Angular y Bootstrap**, ya le voy agarrando la onda pero me sigue dando algunos problemas (mas que nada por no conocer el entorno del Framework), por ejemplo, antes no me mostraba mis componentes al agregarlos en el *index*, hasta que note que solo reconocía su *app-root*, ahora tengo el problema de que al intentar usar los iconos de **Bootstrap** (instalados desde NPM) estos no se muestran a menos que sea por link web, lo que me hace pensar que el error esta en mis rutas, alguien que ya haya trabajado con el Framework podría ayudarme a saber cual es mi error exactamente?

PD: Para no tener problemas con nada instale las versiones mas actuales de Node, Angular y Bootstrap, ademas mi paquete de iconos de guardo de manera automática en la carpeta `node_modules`

Ok, gracias a todos por su ayuda, no se que movi o como le hice

Pero ya se muestran xd

Comment: Angular 17 salió hace menos de dos semanas, la mayoría de los paquetes que existen no están actualizados aún, por otro lado estás seguro que haces todos los pasos para usar bootstrap? Usualmente tienes que importas cosas en el package.json y en el CSS. Si agregas el código será más fácil de ver qué está mal

Comment: @René Entonces es posible que los iconos no aparezcan porque aun no soporta su uso la ultima version?
O porque no tiene los enlaces correctos
Ya tengo todo importado en `package`, pero aun con todo eso no me deja mostrarlos

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que agregar lo que instalaste con npm al `angular.json`, vas a ver que tenes un apartado `styles:[]`, y otro `scripts:[]`, ahí dentro tenes que colocar el path.

```
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

Comment: Ya tengo agregado el CSS de Bootstrap, lo único que no puedo usar son los iconos, en tutoriales dicen que es agregando su ruta css, pero aun haciendo eso y teniendo diferentes llamadas (en singular, no al mismo tiempo) no me sale